# Inner curved box with css3, is this possible?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering is this possible to make in css3 or it needs to be done with .png ?

If its possible to make an inner circle then maybe just add width for example 400% and you get this slight curve of the circle ? Thanks !!!!

SCREENSHOT:

http://oi34.tinypic.com/xya89.jpg

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS 3 Shape: "Inverse Circle" or "Cut Out Circle"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501488/css-3-shape-inverse-circle-or-cut-out-circle)