# How to create one side circular effect

Tags: html, css

hi all developers and webdesigners , i want to create a one side circular effect with twitter bootstrap , something like [this picture](http://img.ir/cfjc.jpg) . there is a circular curve on the left side and rectangular straight line on the right side , but the rectangular has an effect on it's left side which you can see in the picture , how can i create something like this ?
Thanks.

Comment: what does this have to do with bootstrap?

Comment: @Mostafa Safarian image can't show here. please re update image

Comment: There is a similar question on SO. There are some solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501488/css-3-shape-inverse-circle-or-cut-out-circle

Comment: Thank you keaukraine ! that's what i want .

Answer (score 0):

Try this for circular image.

***HTML:***

```
<div class="circular"></div>
```

***CSS:***

```
.circular {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 150px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
  -moz-border-radius: 150px;
  background: url(http://link-to-your/image.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

**Or**

***HTML:***

```
<div class="circular"><img src="http://link-to-your/image.jpg" alt="" /></div>
```

***CSS:***

```
.circular {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 150px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
    -moz-border-radius: 150px;
    background: url(http://link-to-your/image.jpg) no-repeat;
}

.circular img {
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sc4Gt/)**

Comment: Check demo here http://jsfiddle.net/sc4Gt/

Answer (score 0):

Like this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FTCLa/)**

**css**

```
.circle {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 150px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
  -moz-border-radius: 150px;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

like this more [links](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/08/09/building-a-circular-navigation-with-css-transforms/)

Answer (score 0):

### Take a look at [*this demo*](http://jsfiddle.net/thP42/show/)

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-color: #555;
}
#outer {
    margin: 100px auto;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 200px;
}

#inner {
    width: 200px; height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/fqct5Us.gif) center;
    border-radius: 1000px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 10px solid black;
    float: left;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.4);
       -moz-transform: scale(1.4);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.4);
         -o-transform: scale(1.4);
            transform: scale(1.4);
}

#inner:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px; width: 50px;
    left: 30px; bottom: -110px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: black;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
         -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
            transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="outer">
        I am lorem. &larr; Huh?
    <div id="inner">
    </div>
</div>
```