# CSS3 background carve or radius issue

Tags: css

I am trying to create background carve in CSS. Take a look in the picture below.

[image: Image Carve!]

How can I add radius like this in CSS3? Anyone can help?

Comment: Check this question: [CSS3 Shape Inverse Circle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501488/css-3-shape-inverse-circle-or-cut-out-circle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
border-top-left-radius: 50%;
border-top-right-radius: 50%;
```

I made an example of it here: http://jsfiddle.net/DFs6H/2/

Answer (score 0):

Add another div on the bottom with a border radius.

html:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="bottom_border"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.content{
    background:#CCC;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    position:relative;
   overflow:hidden
}
.bottom_border {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    background:#FFF;
    width:100px;
    height:20px;
    top:90px;
    bottom:-10px;
    border-radius: 50%
}
```