# Clip path inset circle?

Tags: css, css-shapes, clip-path

Is it possible to create an inset circle clip path so that the clip path would effectively cut a hole through the div in the center opposed to only showing the center?

The div should all be shown apart from a hole cut out in the center to create something like this:

[image: cut out circle]

I would like to use clip path or something similar so that I can have stuff (images and content) behind the div and the clip path will be used to reveal this. So the div (blue div from my jsfiddle) will disappear from the center using a transition to show the content behind it.

```css
div {
  background: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(50px at center);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pm4yvbxn/

Comment: could you attach an image to show exactly what you want?

Comment: What exacly is your aim? Is there a reason you want to use the clip-path property?

Comment: @web-tiki I would like to use clip path or something similar so that I can have stuff (images and content) behind the div and the clip path will be used to reveal this.

So the div (blue div from my jsfiddle) will disappear from the center using a transition to show the content behind it.

Comment: Hi - were you able to figure out a way to do this using clip-path?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve this with `clip-path` but you can certainly cut a hole in a `div` using the `radial-gradient` background images. This has much better browser support than `clip-path` too.

**Note:** This approach (and `box-shadow` ) will work only when the element that is covering the content below has a colored fill. If instead of `sandybrown` color, there needs to be another image on top then these approaches will not work because they don't actually *cut a hole*, they just mimic that effect.

```css
.div-with-hole {
  height: 100vh;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at center, transparent 25%, sandybrown 25.5%);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}
.div-with-hole:hover {
  background-size: 400% 400%; /* should be 100% * (100 / transparent % of radial gradient */
}
body {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/800/800/nature/1);
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='div-with-hole'></div>
```

Comment: there is also a mix-blend-mode approach (yep, not for IE) :)

Answer (score 11):

You can create hole in  `clip-path` with this approach:

```js
let precision = 64;
let radius = 25;
let c = [...Array(precision)].map((_, i) => {
  let a = -i/(precision-1)*Math.PI*2;
  let x = Math.cos(a)*radius + 50;
  let y = Math.sin(a)*radius + 50;
  return `${x}% ${y}%`
})

document.querySelector('div').style.clipPath = 
 `polygon(100% 50%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0, 100% 0, 100% 50%, ${c.join(',')})`;
```

```css
div {
  background: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

or symply use resulting clip string:

```css
div {
      background: blue;
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
    }
```

```html
<div style="clip-path: polygon(100% 50%, 100% 100%, 0px 100%, 0px 0px, 100% 0px, 100% 50%, 75% 50%, 74.8758% 47.5108%, 74.5043% 45.0463%, 73.8893% 42.6311%, 73.0369% 40.2891%, 71.9555% 38.0437%, 70.656% 35.917%, 69.1511% 33.9303%, 67.4559% 32.1033%, 65.5872% 30.4542%, 63.5637% 28.9994%, 61.4053% 27.7532%, 59.1335% 26.7282%, 56.771% 25.9344%, 54.3412% 25.3798%, 51.8683% 25.0699%, 49.3767% 25.0078%, 46.8914% 25.194%, 44.437% 25.6268%, 42.0378% 26.3018%, 39.7178% 27.2124%, 37.5% 28.3494%, 35.4064% 29.7015%, 33.4579% 31.2555%, 31.6737% 32.9957%, 30.0717% 34.9049%, 28.6677% 36.9641%, 27.4758% 39.1529%, 26.5077% 41.4495%, 25.7731% 43.8311%, 25.2792% 46.2739%, 25.0311% 48.7539%, 25.0311% 51.2461%, 25.2792% 53.7261%, 25.7731% 56.1689%, 26.5077% 58.5505%, 27.4758% 60.8471%, 28.6677% 63.0359%, 30.0717% 65.0951%, 31.6737% 67.0043%, 33.4579% 68.7445%, 35.4064% 70.2985%, 37.5% 71.6506%, 39.7178% 72.7876%, 42.0378% 73.6982%, 44.437% 74.3732%, 46.8914% 74.806%, 49.3767% 74.9922%, 51.8683% 74.9301%, 54.3412% 74.6202%, 56.771% 74.0656%, 59.1335% 73.2718%, 61.4053% 72.2468%, 63.5637% 71.0006%, 65.5872% 69.5458%, 67.4559% 67.8967%, 69.1511% 66.0697%, 70.656% 64.083%, 71.9555% 61.9563%, 73.0369% 59.7109%, 73.8893% 57.3689%, 74.5043% 54.9537%, 74.8758% 52.4892%, 75% 50%);"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works flawlessly. Small note for others — keep in mind that 'radius' must be in %, not pixels.

Answer (score 10):

`mask` can do this and it will work with any kind of background:

```css
div {
  background: linear-gradient(blue, red);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-mask: radial-gradient(50px, #0000 98%, #000);
          mask: radial-gradient(50px, #0000 98%, #000);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Can also be animated:

```css
div {
  background: linear-gradient(blue,red);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-mask:
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,#000 98%,#0000) center/50px 50px no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(#000 0 0);
  -webkit-mask-composite:destination-out;
   
  mask:
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,#000 98%,#0000) center/50px 50px no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(#000 0 0);
  mask-composite:exclude;
  transition:0.5s;
}
div:hover {
  -webkit-mask-size:290px 290px,auto;
          mask-size:290px 290px,auto;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Mask is much better for animations ! Thanks mate ;)

Answer (score 6):

You could also do this with `box-shadow` on `:after` pseudo-element

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url('http://planetcompas.com/live/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/2015-01-Beautiful-Planet-And-Space-4-Cool-Wallpapers-HD.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
div:after {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  content: '';
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 300px lightblue;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
div:hover:after {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

SVG mask solution

A circle is used as a mask, and its radius is animated.

*The animation will start after clicking on the image*

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 600 600" >  
     <defs>
         <!-- Multicolor radial gradient -->
     <radialGradient id="grad" x1="0" y1="0" x2="100%" y2="0">

        <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#48afc1" />
        <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#b4c63b" />
       <stop offset="20%" stop-color="#ef5b2b" />
       <stop offset="20%" stop-color="#503969" />
        <stop offset="30%" stop-color="#ab6294" />
        <stop offset="30%" stop-color="#1cb98f" />
        <stop offset="40%" stop-color="#48afc1" />
        <stop offset="40%" stop-color="#b4c63b" />
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#ef5b2b" />
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#503969" />  
        <stop offset="60%" stop-color="#ab6294" />
        <stop offset="60%" stop-color="#1cb98f" />
       <stop offset="70%" stop-color="#48afc1" />
        <stop offset="70%" stop-color="#b4c63b" />
        <stop offset="80%" stop-color="#ef5b2b" />
        <stop offset="80%" stop-color="#503969" />
        <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#ab6294" />
        <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#1cb98f" />
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#48afc1" />
     </radialGradient>
         <!-- Mask -->
     <mask id="msk1" > 
            <rect  width="100%" height="100%"  fill="black" /> 
             
       <circle cx="300" cy="300"  r="0" fill="white" >
            <!-- Animation of a mask cutting through the image of a dragon and showing a radial gradient  -->
         <animate attributeName="r" begin="svg1.click" dur="8s" values="0;300;300;0;0" fill="freeze" repeatCount="3" />
        </circle>
     </mask>
     </defs> 
               <!-- Radial gradient background image  -->
      <circle  cx="300" cy="300"  r="300"  fill="url(#grad)"  />  
                 
          <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kywq.png" x="-140" y="-60" mask="url(#msk1)" width="800" height="780" />  

</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Stranger in the Q's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63739677/5492980) I created a dynamic solution for this problem.

My method works with `rem, em, px`, and `percent` as well also uses attributes on the element.

```js
function parseUnitsToPercent(str, divider){
  var match = str.match(/^calc\((.+)\);?$/);
  if(match){
    var val = [...match[1].matchAll(/((?:\d(?:\.\d)?)+(?:px|rem|em|%)?)(?:\s([\+|\-|\*|\/])\s)?/g)].map(e=>e.slice(1)).flat().filter(e=>!!e);
    val = val.map(e=>{
      if(['+','-','*','/'].includes(e)){
        return e;
      }
      return convertUnitsToPercent(e, divider);
    });
    try {
      str = eval(val.join(' '));
    } catch(e){
      str = 0;
    }
  }
  return convertUnitsToPercent(str, divider); 
}
function convertUnitsToPercent(str, divider){
  if(str.toString().endsWith('rem')) {
    str = parseFloat(str) * parseFloat(getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).fontSize) + 'px';
  }
  if(str.toString().endsWith('em')) {
    str = parseFloat(str) * parseFloat(getComputedStyle(elem).fontSize) + 'px';
  }
  if(str.toString().endsWith('px')) {
    str = parseFloat(str)/divider*100;
  }
  if(str.toString().endsWith('%')) {
    str = parseFloat(str);
  }
  return str;
}
document.querySelectorAll('[clip-x][clip-y][clip-size]').forEach(elem=>{
  if(elem.getAttribute('width')) elem.style.width = elem.getAttribute('width') + 'px';
  if(elem.getAttribute('height')) elem.style.height = elem.getAttribute('height') + 'px';
  var x = elem.getAttribute('clip-x');
  var y = elem.getAttribute('clip-y');
  var size = elem.getAttribute('clip-size');
  var elem_size = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  x = parseUnitsToPercent(x, elem_size.width);
  y = parseUnitsToPercent(y, elem_size.height);
  var radius_x = parseUnitsToPercent(size, elem_size.width);
  var radius_y = parseUnitsToPercent(size, elem_size.height);
  var precision = parseFloat(elem.getAttribute('clip-precision') || 64);
  var c = [...Array(precision)].map((_, i) => {
    var a = -i/(precision-1)*Math.PI*2;
    var _x = Math.cos(a)*radius_x + x;
    var _y = Math.sin(a)*radius_y + y;
    return `${_x}% ${_y}%`
  });
  elem.style.clipPath = `polygon(100% 50%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0, 100% 0, 100% 50%, ${c.join(',')})`;
});
```

```css
div {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div clip-x="50%" clip-y="calc(50% + 20px)" clip-size="50px" clip-precision="64" width="400" height="200"></div>
```

I know this question is really old, but I found it really useful so I modified it for myself. I decided to share with you my result.

My code supports `calc()` as well (Please note: It uses `eval()` which makes it insecure for user-input codes!)

Answer (score -2):

You can do it by adding an elements in `<div>`.

I have used `<span>`. Here is the code

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div{
  background: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(50px at center);
  position:relative;
}
div span{
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  border-radius:100%;
  background:#fff;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%)
}
```

example : https://jsfiddle.net/pm4yvbxn/2/

> You can also use `border-radius` in div for rounded borders.

Comment: Sorry I might not of been entirely clear, ive updated the question with an image of what I am looking for. Its to make the clip path punch a hole in the center of the div instead of only showing the center of the div.

Comment: Thats not what I mean. Im wanting it so that instead of the clip path only showing the center circle of the div it should clip a circle out of the center of the div so that everything but the center circle is shown.