# CSS: Colored div with transparent box

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to have a div with a background-color that takes up 100% width and a transparent box inside it that shows the original background? [image]

Comment: You mean a window?

Comment: Just change the circle http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37000558/clip-path-inset-circle/37001333#37001333

Comment: Can you please give us your HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Solution 1: Clip-path

Clip path can be quite useful, as it keeps the code clean and simple. However, it does not have great support (yet) in browsers, and should hence only be used in test environments.

```css
html {
  background: url("http://butlers-web.co.uk/Content/Images/BWLOGO.png") 100% 100%;
}
div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background: tomato;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0, 50% 0, 50% 20%, 80% 20%, 80% 80%, 20% 80%, 20% 20%, 50% 20%, 50% 0);
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```

## Solution 2: Box shadow Trick

The box shadow trick uses a pseudo element and `overflow:hidden;` to create the box shadow/colouring of the element.

```css
html {
  background: url("http://butlers-web.co.uk/Content/Images/BWLOGO.png") 100% 100%;
}
div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
overflow:hidden;
  position: relative;
}
div:before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:20%;width:60%;height:60%;left:20%;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 999px tomato;
  }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

## Solution 3: Gradients

You could use multiple gradient background, however this may or may not be suitable as gradients don't always turn out rendered very nicely:

```css
html {
   background: url("http://butlers-web.co.uk/Content/Images/BWLOGO.png") 100% 100%;
 }
 div {
   position: relative;
   height: 300px;
   width: 100%;
   background: linear-gradient(tomato, tomato), linear-gradient(tomato, tomato), linear-gradient(tomato, tomato), linear-gradient(tomato, tomato);
   background-size: 100% 20%, 20% 100%, 100% 20%, 20% 100%;
   background-position: left bottom, right bottom, left top, left top;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

## Solution 4: Borders

Whilst this may or may not be suitable for you, there is still a chance that it may help, so will post here anyway:

```css
html {
   background: url("http://butlers-web.co.uk/Content/Images/BWLOGO.png") 100% 100%;
 }
 div {
   position: relative;
   height: 300px;
   width: 100%;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   border-left: 20vw solid tomato;
   border-right: 20vw solid tomato;
   border-top: 50px solid tomato;
   border-bottom: 50px solid tomato;
 }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

## Solution 5: Background attachment

I have recently come across the `background-attachment` property, so am still coming to grips with it. However, if you wished the background to appear behind you may be able to alter the below snippet to your needs:

```css
body {
  background: url('http://butlers-web.co.uk/Content/Images/BWLOGO.png');
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: tomato;
  position: relative;
}
.inner {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  background: url('http://butlers-web.co.uk/Content/Images/BWLOGO.png');
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border:2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: For "Solution 1: Clip-path": Is there a way for Firefox/ IE?

Comment: @Aloso As mentioned, [clip path isn't very well supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path).

Answer (score -1):

You're going to need two div for that. A parent, with the red background, then the inner div.

give the inner div  margin: 10px auto; as a start.

Comment: OP does not **have** to use two divs, as demonstrated in the link @Nenad has provided in the comments.

Comment: A child div will have the background rescaled to be smaller.

Comment: never thought of using :after. it works, but may not be the best solution of the child needs to hold something that CSS can't inject.