# How can I cut a hole through multiple divs to the background?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I cut a hole in multiple divs to the body background?

Using clip paths ([Clip path inset circle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37000558/clip-path-inset-circle)) you can cut a hole in a div, potentially animated.

But is there a way to cut through multiple divs, to either the body background, or a nominated parent div?

It would be theoretically possible to use javascript, to copy a clip-path to the parent, however it would need to be adjusted, and I could see animation being a potential issue.

Comment: Won't a `clip-path` on the parent div also clip its children? So you can just add a wrapper div as a common parent to everything that needs to be clipped, and add the clip path to that wrapper.

Comment: can show us a screenshot or an illustration of what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Thomas wow... ok, that's probably the best way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the `radial-gradient` trick, you can just stack the holes on top of each other.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nh3reLg1/2/