# Make Div Transparent on Other Div

Tags: html, css

is it possible to define space with div, and make that defined space transparent, but on the other div? It's hard for me to explain, this picture just says it all:

[image: Explanation]

I have tried to do that with clip-path, but without success, I think "transparency" has to be defined on third DIV, but with clip-path I had to define it on second DIV, which made it unresponsive if third DIV changed position...

IF JS need to be used, please could we stick to vannila JS?

Thanks for any advice!

```css
#first {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: pink;
    width: 320px;
    height: 320px;
    }

#second {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 310px;
    height: 310px;
    }

#third {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    left: 80px;
    top: 80px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="first"></div>
<div id="second"></div>
<div id="third"></div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807286/how-to-make-div-background-color-transparent-in-css

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to cut a rectangular hole in the blue so whatever is behind can be seen - is that right?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it's kind of different case

Comment: @AHaworth yes, that's correct. Sorry for unclear description

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62115874/how-can-i-cut-a-hole-through-multiple-divs-to-the-background

Comment: There are possibilities here but the use case is important. I'd be curious to see a design image. Will there be content in any of the divs, especially the middle one? https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/qBwbmKv

Comment: Can you describe what will be on the lowest layer, div1?Will it be just background (images and/or color) or might it be other stuff like HTML content?

Answer (score 0):

To 'cut' a hole in the second layer div you can use clip-path.

Online clip path tool: https://bennettfeely.com/clippy

Maybe this pen can be used for inspiration https://codepen.io/jakob-e/pen/ExJPvKg

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#first {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: pink;
  width: 320px;
  height: 320px;
}

#second {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 310px;
  height: 310px;

  /* Clip path frame */
  clip-path: polygon(
    0% 0%, 
    0% 100%, 
    26% 100%, 
    26% 26%, 
    78% 26%, 
    78% 78%, 
    26% 78%, 
    26% 100%, 
    100% 100%, 
    100% 0%
  );
}

#third {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  left: 80px;
  top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div id="first"></div>
<div id="second"></div>
<div id="third"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, but how to make that move when div3 moves? (I can see how with JS but can’t see how with pure CSS)

Comment: How are you planing to move the third div?

Comment: It’s not me asking the question!

Comment: Haha, sorry - I would probably do it using CSSVariables e.g. var(--tl) var(--tr) var(--br) var(--bl) defined on a wrapper. Then the variables can be used to set the inset of the 3'rd div and to define the corresponding clip-path points

Comment: Yes, that’s how I’d do it too. I can’t think of a pure CSS solution that meets all cases.

Comment: It very much depends on what the intended goal is. I cooked up a quick (very simplified) example that uses drag and CSSVars to move a crop area on top of an image. 

https://codepen.io/jakob-e/pen/ExJPvKg

Comment: Thanks for replies... There's no problem with vanilla JS if solution is cleaner than pure CSS :)