# Hide elements behind DIV but not background

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have `div.box2` inside `div.box1` and the problem is that I wanted to be able to see the background from the `div.App` (It would be awesome If I also could see other elements behind `div.box2`) in `div.box1` (just like a window) but I can't use `z-index` directly on `div.box2` or `div.box1`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.App {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/326055/pexels-photo-326055.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1);
}

@keyframes moveAround {
  0% {
    left: 50px;
  }
  50% {
    left: 25px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 50px;
  }
}

.box1 {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: aqua;
  animation: moveAround 3s infinite ease;
}

.box2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="App">
  <div class="box1">
    <div class="box2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't really understand why you can't implement the background on div2. Can you put the code into your question rather than on an external site (which may disappear in future, making the question useless for others) and include something about the movement you are wanting. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I just have a feeling that implementing a scaled background on div.box2 would come with a lot of pain, especially when it comes to moving the box or scaling the background when needed.

But it would be awesome if there is a pixel-perfect solution.

Comment: I now don't understand 'scaled background'! Have you considered a combination of clip-path and the background image also on say the after pseudo element of box2? If there is a scaling requirement, please include it in your question. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I think this might work. I found this StackOverflow question that has many helpful answers and I think I might be able to work something out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37000558/clip-path-inset-circle

Answer (score 1):

One way of getting this effect is to have an after pseudo element on box2 which has the same background image as App and overlays it.

This snippet then clips box2 so only that part of the image that covers box2 is shown.

This gives the appearance of a hole having been punched in box1.

```html
<style>
  * {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .App {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/326055/pexels-photo-326055.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: pink;
  }
  
  .box1 {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: aqua;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  @keyframes move {
    0%,
    100% {
      margin-left: -400px;
      margin-top: -400px;
    }
    50% {
      margin-left: 200px;
      margin-top: 200px;
    }
  }
  
  .box2 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
    animation: move 4s infinite;
  }
  
  .box2::after {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/326055/pexels-photo-326055.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div class="App">
    <div class="box1">
      <div class="box2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `.box2` as a "window", why not just get rid of it?

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.App {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/326055/pexels-photo-326055.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1);
}

@keyframes moveAround {
  0% {
    left: 50px;
  }
  50% {
    left: 25px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 50px;
  }
}

.box1 {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  border:solid 25px aqua;
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 2px blue;
  animation: moveAround 3s infinite ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="App">
  <div class="box1">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry but I need to keep the `.box2`

Comment: @TomaszOlek, why?

Comment: I need to be able to set an image in `.box 1` and `.box 2`(transparent image) but the image in `.box 1` does not always have a transparent background/spots. So in a way, I need `.box 2` to act like a cut-out for `.box 1`, to view the background of the page.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.App {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/326055/pexels-photo-326055.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1);
}

@keyframes moveAround {
  0% {
    left: 50px;
  }
  50% {
    left: 25px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 50px;
  }
}

.box1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  animation: moveAround 3s infinite ease;
    border: 25px solid aqua;
}

.box2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="App">
  <div class="box1">
    <div class="box2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

change css this way.

remove in box1 class in background and add border so it work.

I hope it work for your requirement Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As an option, you can add `.box1 { overflow: hidden; }` and `.box2 { box-shadow:0 0 0 100vmin aqua; }`:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.App {
  min-height: 100dvh;
  background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/326055/pexels-photo-326055.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1);
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
}

@keyframes moveAround {
  50% {
    transform: translateX(100px);
  }
}

.box1 {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px;
}

.box2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vmin aqua;
  animation: moveAround 3s infinite ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="App">
  <div class="box1">
    <div class="box2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```