# CSS Transparent border effect on overlapping elements

Tags: css, html

I'm struggling to find a solution about achieving this particular effect:

[image]

The tricky part is that I need the circle and the rectangle to be 2 separate elements because they will contain child nodes.

I've tried various ways, including `border`s with transparent colors, `shape-` properties, element positioning trickery etc. Unfortunately, none of my trials yielded even at least approximate results. I just can't seem to be able to wrap my head around this and I can't find any examples on the web as well. The closest I got to was [this thread](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/shapes/getting-started/).

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: could do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501488/css-3-shape-inverse-circle-or-cut-out-circle

Comment: Wow, there are some really interesting ideas in that thread. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `radial-gradient` you can easily do this:

```css
.rect {
 margin-top:50px;
 height:120px;
 background:radial-gradient(circle at center,transparent 100px, green 100.5px);
}
.circle {
  margin:-150px auto 0;
  width:180px;
  height:180px;
  background:green;
  border-radius:50%;
}

html {
 background:linear-gradient(to right,pink,white);
 height:100%
}
```

```html
<div class="rect">
</div>
<div class="circle">
</div>
```