# How to make right arc in a circle using SVG?

Tags: html, svg

I am trying to make an arc like cut at the right of svg circle.

**Current Result:**

```css
.ant-avatar-group {
    display: inline-flex;
}

.ant-avatar {
   width: 38px;
   height: 38px;
   line-height: 38px;
   font-size: 19px;
   background: #ccc;
   border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="ant-avatar-group">
<svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<circle opacity="0.15" cx="20" cy="20" r="19" fill="#F6BB43" stroke="white" stroke-width="2">
</circle>
</svg>

<span class="ant-avatar"> </span>
</div>
```

**Expected Result:**

[image]

**Code Tried:**

Changed,  `cx="20"` **to** `cx="30"`

Also adding,

`margin-left: -8px;` and `border-left: 4px solid #fff` to `.ant-avatar` makes the avatar icon to distort (loose its original size) of the right avatar circle.

```css
.ant-avatar-group {
    display: inline-flex;
}

.ant-avatar {
   width: 38px;
   height: 38px;
   line-height: 38px;
   font-size: 19px;
   background: #ccc;
   border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="ant-avatar-group">
<svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<circle opacity="0.15" cx="30" cy="20" r="19" fill="#F6BB43" stroke="white" stroke-width="2">
</circle>
</svg>

<span class="ant-avatar"> </span>
</div>
```

But this doesn't give the expected output as there needs to be arc like cut. Kindly help me to achieve the result making the svg circle with right arc as like the given expected result.

Big thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10503105/17235431

Comment: @GeekyQuentin, Not what I am looking for as I am going in svg way of approach.

Comment: Why don't you import an already concaved svg icon?

Comment: as you are moving the cx part of the svg circle will fall outside the svg canvas. I would put both circles in svg.

Comment: @enxaneta, Could you provide a solution on how to achieve it? The left circle alone svg in my real app and right side circle is a normal div as like mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I've commented I would put both circles in svg. For the image you can use clipPath to cut it in a circle shape.

For the other circle I'm usinga mask so that you can see through, since the mask is cutting a circular hole in it.

In CSS I've added a background to the svg. You can remove it

```css
svg{width:300px; background:#efefef}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 60 40">
  <defs>
    <mask id="m">
      <rect fill="white" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="40" />
      <circle cx="40" cy="20" r="18" fill="blabk" />
    </mask>
    <clipPath id="clip">
      <circle cx="40" cy="20" r="16" fill="00f" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <circle opacity="1" cx="20" cy="20" r="16" fill="#F6BB43" mask="url(#m)" />

  <image href="https://assets.codepen.io/222579/darwin300.jpg" x="21" y="2" width="35" height="35" clip-path="url(#clip)" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

Taking enxanetas'answer

Problem with inline SVGs is the ID values need to be unique **per** SVG,
or any following SVG will use the first defined mask/clip-path IDs

You can create those IDs dynamically:

```css
svg {
  width: 250px;
  background: #efefef
}
```

```html
<svg-avatar fill="#4267B2" href="https://i.imgur.com/iCKbSvQ.png"></svg-avatar>
<svg-avatar href="https://i.imgur.com/zTUDE6c.png"></svg-avatar>

<script>
  customElements.define("svg-avatar", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      let id = n => n + Math.random() * 1e18; // create a unique id
      let maskid = id("mask");
      let clipid = id("clip");
      this.innerHTML = 
`<svg viewBox="0 0 60 40">
<defs>
<mask id="${maskid}"><rect fill="white"x="0"y="0"width="100"height="40"/><circle cx="40"cy="20"r="18"/></mask>
<clipPath id="${clipid}"><circle cx="40"cy="20"r="16"fill="00f"/></clipPath>
</defs>
<circle mask="url(#${maskid})"fill="${this.getAttribute("fill")||"#F6BB43"}"opacity="1"cx="20"cy="20"r="16"/>
<image href="${this.getAttribute("href")}"clip-path="url(#${clipid})"x="21"y="2"width="35"height="35"/>
</svg>`
}});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the alternative you could just add another white circle that overlaps the existing one.... look here

```
 <div class="ant-avatar-group">
  <svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle opacity="0.15" cx="20" cy="20" r="19" fill="#F6BB43" stroke="white" stroke-width="2">
    </circle>
    <circle opacity="1" cx="47" cy="20" r="19" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="white" stroke-width="2">
    </circle>
   </svg>

   <span class="ant-avatar"> </span>
</div>
```

That will generate the arc but you still to set the negative margin-left to .ant-avatar to overlap the svg...

Comment: This leads to more space than expected in the middle.

Comment: You still have to set the negative margin-left to overlap the .ant-avatar to svg.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.ant-avatar-group {
    display: inline-flex;
    position:relative;
}

.ant-avatar {
  position:absolute;
  left:25px;
   width: 38px;
   height: 38px;
   line-height: 38px;
   font-size: 19px;
   background: #ccc;
   border:3px solid white;
   border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="ant-avatar-group">
    <svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <circle opacity="0.15" cx="20" cy="20" r="19" fill="#F6BB43" stroke="white" stroke-width="2">
      </circle>
    </svg>
    <span class="ant-avatar"> </span>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

circle in svg should have cx="20" because the circle can't go out of it's parent... you should overlap the .ant-avatar over the svg using something like

```
.ant-avatar {
   margin-left: -10px;
}
```

Comment: That's because an element inside of a svg can't go "outside" the dimensions specified for the svg.

Comment: This just overlap one on another but I am in the need of white pace between two.

Comment: in .ant-avatar add `border: 5px solid white` after you set the negative margin left

Comment: @GicuAftene, please understand the question, don't provide alternative solutions which are not asked for

Comment: After that you should modify some others fields to align in the middle the elements.

Comment: @GicuAftene, Adding, `margin-left: -8px;` and `border-left: 4px solid #fff` to `.ant-avatar` makes the avatar icon to distort (loose its original size) of the right avatar circle.

Comment: added another solution that generate the arc that @HelloWorld requested for

Comment: @GeekyQuentin "How to make right arc in a circle using css?" that's the question