# CSS 3 Shape: inverted rounded corner "tunnel-like style"

Tags: css, css-shapes

I am looking to create a tunnel-like div which has inverted circle borders

[image: comp design]

As you can see it has an 'expanding tunnel effect' from left to right. Ideally the checkered background is transparent but if that is impossible I can maybe make it work with a solid background color.

Can anyone help me out creating this css3 shape? Hopefully with a jsfiddle that I can play with?

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS3 Inverted Rounded Corner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936262/css3-inverted-rounded-corner)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be created using a `:before` and `:after` pseudo element:

[image: Screenshot completed]

- The background colour is provided with the `box-shadow` colour, allowing the top and bottom of the shape to be transparent
- The curve is created with the `border-radius` like so:

  (the red area is transparent)

  [image: Screenshot]

### Complete Example

```css
div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div:before {
  top: -60px;
  border-bottom: solid #EEE;
  border-right: solid #EEE;
  border-radius: 0 0 60% 0;
  box-shadow: 50px 10px 0 60px #F90;
}
div:after {
  bottom: -60px;
  box-shadow: 50px 10px 0 60px #F90;
  border-radius: 0 60% 0 0;
  border-top: solid #EEE;
  border-right: solid #EEE;
}
div:before,
div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 160px;
  right: 0;
  border-width: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```